# How can I remove the GMSPolyline in Swift 3

Tags: google-maps, swift3, polyline

I'm making the GMSPolyline in the GoogleMap. When I want to remove the GMSPolyline by coding `polyline.map = nil`, but it can not working for me. I'm copy some coding in the below.

(added the marker before, I need remove the polyline only)

Thank you for your help!!!

my coding:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    //MARK: create the GMSPolyline
    let polyline = GMSPolyline()
    //MARK: remove the old polyline from the GoogleMap 
    polyline.map = nil

    let origin = "\(mapView.myLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(mapView.myLocation!.coordinate.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(marker.position.latitude),\(marker.position.longitude)"

    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

        //MARK: print route using Polyline
        for route in routes
        {
            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
            let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points!)
            polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeWidth = 4
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow
            polyline.isTappable = true
            polyline.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should clear the map before adding new polyline on the map.

clear() function of GMSMapView

```
/**

Clears all markup that has been added to the map, including markers, polylines and ground overlays.
This will not clear the visible location dot or reset the current mapType.

*/
```

Try this

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    //MARK: create the GMSPolyline
    let polyline = GMSPolyline()
    //MARK: remove the old polyline from the GoogleMap 
    mapView.clear()
    //TODO:- Redraw all marker here.
    let origin = "\(mapView.myLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(mapView.myLocation!.coordinate.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(marker.position.latitude),\(marker.position.longitude)"

    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

        //MARK: print route using Polyline
        for route in routes
        {
            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
            let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points!)
            polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeWidth = 4
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow
            polyline.isTappable = true
            polyline.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I'm added the markers to the map, if I'm using mapView.clear() witch will be deleted the marks?

Comment: @ShingHung you have to redraw all marker after clear the mapView.Then it will work in the way you expect. Also Edited the answer. Please have a look to this.

Comment: The lag and lat of markers were got from JSON, if I redraw the markers, I'm using more data.

Comment: but i think that the only way. Although you have to update marker also when updating polyline , if not you can store them in local variables

Comment: Welcome, You can mark the answer right if you thing it works as per your expectation. You can set the zoom level on mapView so that it can fit in iphone visible screen.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me how to show the marker info window, called the `mapView.clear()` after

Comment: Add these line to GMSMapView  at center of your marker and set zoom level according so that all marker get visible.                                                          func setUpGoogleMap(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    //set map here..
    let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinates, zoom: 14)
    mapView.animate(with: cameraUpdate)
  }

Comment: what coding I need tying? for sowing the info window

Comment: i cann't get the "info window" ,  can you please post other question on stack overflow with the code you have and tag me for answer so i can get you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146073/discussion-between-suryakantsharma-and-shinghung).

Answer (score 0):

Declare polyline outside the function as a class property.

```
var routePolyline: GMSPolyline? = nil
```

Then to clear old polyline before adding new one, use-

```
self.routePolyline?.map = nil
```

This will work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

```
   for poll in mapkit.overlays {

            mapkit.removeOverlay(poll)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var polyline: GMSPolyline?

 func drawPathOnMap()  {
        if polyline != nil {
          //remove existing the gmspoly line from your map
             polyline!.map = nil
        }

        let points = //Your Point
        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points)
        polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline?.strokeWidth = 5.0
        polyline?.strokeColor = UIColor.init(rgb: 0x7688ED)
        polyline!.map = mapView
 }
```