# got data from function to array not working in swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, function, swift3

I can get the JSON data but I can not add the JSON data to `abcArr`. I have count the `abcArr` witch is `0` in the `viewDidLoad()`.

I'm copy the coding in below.

Thank you for your help.

my coding:

```
class MapDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var abcArr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getInfo()
        print("1: \(abcArr.count)")//output = 0
    }

    func getInfo() {
        //MARK: get News data JSON
        jsonURL = "http://json/abc.json"

        if let url = NSURL(string: jsonURL) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    if let data = data {
                        let json = JSON(data: data)
                        let jsonReturn = json["return"]
                        let abc = jsonReturn[i]["Lat"]
                        abcArr.append(abc)      
                    } else {
                        print("no JSON data")
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
            print("2: \(abcArr.count)")//output = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are accessing this `abcArr` array

Comment: I'm edited my coding. Thank you for your reminded

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. `dataTask` works asynchronously. The data is returned later. Put the line `print(abcArr.count)` at the end of the completion handler.

Comment: @ShingHung vadian is right you need to access `abcArr` inside the completion block because `dataTask` works async so your `print(abcArr.count)` will called before you get response

Comment: my coding is working? Because it postpone to push data to array so I count and print the array which will display 0?

Comment: @NiravD How can I call the abcArr?

Comment: I'm adding the `print(abcArr.count)` to getInfo() of function at final } above, but it is same problem which display `0`

Comment: As @vadian told you, dataTask is async call (it takes time), so when you are printing your array, it didn't finish yet :)

Comment: @beretis can you give me the solution? I can't understand where I need change the coding

Comment: Please read my comment (and the suggestion) again. The `completionHandler` is the scope between the two braces after the parameter label. Move the print line inside the scope at the end of the first `else` clause.

Comment: @vadian Thank you very much. it's done! my bad. Sorry

Comment: do your print after "abcArr.append(abc)" is what @vadian ment

Comment: @vadian Could you please help me some problem on another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393200/how-can-i-remove-the-gmspolyline-in-swift-3)

Comment: You got help in this post. I'm not familiar with MapKit

Comment: @vadian OK. Thank you Vadian!!

Comment: @EricAya OK, Sorry

Comment: @EricAya OK!! Sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your solution Vadian.

Put the line print(abcArr.count) at the end of the completion handler.

```
class MapDetailViewController: UIViewController {
     var abcArr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getInfo()
    }

    func getInfo() {
        //MARK: get News data JSON
        jsonURL = "http://json/abc.json"

        if let url = NSURL(string: jsonURL) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    if let data = data {
                        let json = JSON(data: data)
                        let jsonReturn = json["return"]
                        let abc = jsonReturn[i]["Lat"]
                        abcArr.append(abc)      
                    } else {
                        print("no JSON data")
                    }
                    print("1: \(abcArr.count)")// display abcArr of count
                }
            print("2: \(abcArr.count)")// display abcArr of count
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

my JSON:

```
{
    return: [{
        lat: "1111",
    }]
}
```

Comment: Where the variable i in your handler goes from?

Comment: my JSON having one value only so I can not use the looping

Comment: if you need make the looping, you can make let `json = JSON(data: data)` line after

Comment: Print the i value as well, and answer where is the value from

Comment: @user3441734 There are other issues the compiler is supposed to complain about (missing `self` and type mismatch `JSON – String` in the  `abcArr.append(abc)` line)